# How to populate sections of an indexed UITableView with different array for sectionIndexTitles

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm using an array of people's names to load a table. I want to separate the sections based on each person's state of residence while keeping the sectionIndexTitles limited to the first letter of the state's name. My sectionIndexTitles would be i.e. ["A", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W"] while the table sections would be separated into all 50 states.

In essence, the letter A (index 0) would belong to Alaska, Alabama, Arkansas, and Arizona. There is no B so the next letter C (index 2) should scroll to California which has a section count of 4.

The problem I run into is that the sections are obviously not properly indexed therefore when tapping on any indexed title other than the letter A, the tableview does not scroll to the proper letter.

Comment: Do you have array of people objects? Show the tableview datasource methods

Comment: Yes, people objects. I didn't add the methods because it has a lot of extra stuff unrelated to the question. Search bar, segmented control to switch between order by last name or order by state name. I don't want to make it more complicated than it needs to be. I can send it to you if you'd like. I just didn't want to clutter the question/issue.

Comment: Did you check my answer. Do you understand this?

Comment: Yes I did. It works great but is giving me repeated letters in the sectionIndexTitles.

Comment: That created an unordered sectionIndexTitles array and tapping on the letters doesn't scroll properly. The original is better.

Comment: Try `return Array(Set(groupedPeople.map({ String($0.state.first!) }))).sorted()` I don't have big list to test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193778/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-jose-carrillo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the people array by the state name and create array of tuple from the dictionary. Then use that array in tableview data source methods

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    struct Person {
        var name: String
        var state: String
    }
    var allPeople = [Person]()
    var groupedPeople = [(state:String, people:[Person])]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        allPeople = [Person(name: "a", state: "Alaska"), Person(name: "x", state: "Florida"),
                     Person(name: "c", state: "California")]
        groupedPeople = Dictionary(grouping: allPeople, by: { $0.state }).sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
            .map({ (state:$0.key, people:$0.value)
            })
    }
    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return Array(Set(groupedPeople.map({ String($0.state.first!) })))
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return groupedPeople.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return groupedPeople[section].state
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return groupedPeople[section].people.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = groupedPeople[indexPath.section].people[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = groupedPeople[indexPath.section].people[indexPath.row].state
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Update**

When you have more sections than `sectionIndexTitles` you should implement [`sectionForSectionIndexTitle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614933-tableview) method and return appropriate section index.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    if let index = groupedPeople.firstIndex(where: { $0.state.hasPrefix(title) }) {
        return index
    }
    return 0
}
```